# Proof on showing if F(x,y,z)=0 then product of partial derivatives (evaluated at an assigned coordinate) is -1

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The task is as follows:

> **Given:** $$F(x,y,z) = 0$$    **Goal:**  Show    $\frac{\partial
>  z}{\partial y}|_x \frac{\partial  y}{\partial x}|_z \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} |_y = -1$

**Here is my work so far:**

**(1)** Differentiate with respect to y, I get:

$0 + F_2 + F_3  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$

So $ F_3  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = - F_2$

**(2)** Differentiate with respect to x, I get:

$F_1 + F_2 \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}  + 0 = 0$

So $ F_2  \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = - F_1$

**(3)** Differentiate with respect to z, I get:

$F_1  \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}    + 0  + F_3 = 0$

So $ F_1  \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = - F_3$

**(4)** After some manipulations with the $F_i$, I get to the conclusion that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}* \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} * \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}  = -1$, so when evaluated with x, z, y respectively, conclusion is still true

**My questions are:**

(1) Is my proof correct?

(2) For example, when I differentiate with respect to y, I "let" $F_1$ be 0 and find partials for other coordinates.

I had a hard time trying to explain to my friend on the reason(s) why I can do such "let be 0" thing.  Although I think if I can't do that, then there is no way that I can reach the conclusion, but I somehow feel confused about the fact too.  Since my book is doing it that way, my understanding is that I can do such "let be 0" thing based on the independece of x with respect to y, when I differentiate with respect to y.  But is my thought ok?

Would someone please help me on this question?
Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: You should look up Inverse Function Theorem and Implicit Function Theorem

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942457/understanding-frac-partial-x-partial-y-frac-partial-y-partial-z-frac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more simple way is the total differential
$$dF=\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} dx+\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} dy+\frac {\partial F}{\partial z} dz=0$$
If it says "evaluated at $x$" it means that $x$ is fixed and $dx=0$
$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} dy+\frac {\partial F}{\partial z} dz=0\Rightarrow \frac{dz}{dy}=-\frac{\partial F/\partial y}{\partial F/\partial z}$$ 
and similarly
$$dy=0\Rightarrow\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} dx+\frac {\partial F}{\partial z} dz=0\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dz}=-\frac{\partial F/\partial z}{\partial F/\partial x}$$ 
$$dz=0\Rightarrow\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} dx+\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} dy=0\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial y}$$ 
And it follows
$$\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dz}=\bigg(-\frac{\partial F/\partial y}{\partial F/\partial z}\bigg)\bigg(-\frac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(-\frac{\partial F/\partial z}{\partial F/\partial x}\bigg)=-1$$

Comment: If we let $z=y^2+x$ how we can treat $y$ as a function of $x$. It is like saying that $y^2=x−z$ is a function.

Comment: Rather late to answer @user599310 's question, but the (missing) context of this question is that we are discussing defining $x, y, z$ as functions of each other by $F(x,y,z)=0$ on a connected neighborhood of a point where the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to the three variables are non-zero. By the Implicit function theorem, each of the variables can be expressed as a unique function of the others *in this neighborhood*. For your example $F(x,y,z) = x+y^2 - z$, the partial derivative when $y = 0$ is $0$, so the neighborhood cannot include points with $y = 0$.

Comment: This means that $y$ is either everywhere positive or everywhere negative within that neighborhood, allowing us to express either $y = \sqrt{z-x}$ or $y=-\sqrt{z-x}$.