# understanding $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

In particular, when $x=y=z$ isn't the above expression equal to 1 and not -1?

Comment: try reading the above as "a change in x due to a change in y divided by a change in y times a change in y due to a change in z divided by a change in z times a change in z due to a change in x divided by a change in x". Notice that, for example, that "a change in y due to a change in z" and "a change in y" do not represent the same quantity.

Comment: I'll have to think about it more, thanks.

Comment: Older similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345403/prove-that-frac-partial-x-partial-y-frac-partial-y-partial-z-frac-p, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/simplifying-frac-partial-v-partial-t-cdot-frac-partial-t-partial-p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that your comment about letting $x=y=z$ makes no sense at all here.

The formula ("[Barkhausen's tube formula](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkhausensche_R%C3%B6hrenformel)") concerns the situation when there are three quantities $x$, $y$ and $z$ constrained by a relation $F(x,y,z)=0$, so that one can view either one of them as a function of the two others: $x=x(y,z)$ or $y=y(x,z)$ or $z=z(x,y)$.

(At least this holds locally near some point $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ such that $F(a,b,c)=0$, provided that the partial derivatives $F'_x$, $F'_y$ and $F'_z$ all are nonzero at this point, and $F$ is of class $C^1$; this is the implicit function theorem.)

To avoid confusion, write $x=f(y,z)$, $y=g(x,z)$ and $z=h(x,y)$ instead. Then instead of $\partial x/\partial y$ we write $f'_y$, and in particular at the point $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ we write $f'_y(b,c)$, etc. Implicit differentiation shows that
$$
\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \right)\quad
f'_y(b,c)=- \frac{F'_y(a,b,c)}{F_x'(a,b,c)}
,
$$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = \right)\quad
g'_z(a,c)=- \frac{F'_z(a,b,c)}{F_y'(a,b,c)}
,
$$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \right)\quad
h'_x(a,b)=- \frac{F'_x(a,b,c)}{F_z'(a,b,c)}
.
$$
The product of these expressions is $-1$, and that's your formula.

Comment: If we let $z=y^2 + x$ how we can treat $y$ as a function of $x$. It is like saying that $y^2=x-z$ is a function.

Comment: @user599310: You can **locally** consider $y$ as a function of $x$ **and** $z$, in a neighbourhood of any given point $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ such that $b \neq 0$; it's either $y=\sqrt{z-x}$ or $y=-\sqrt{z-x}$, depending on whether $b>0$ or $b<0$. Look up the **implicit function theorem**.