# Generalization of the triple product rule

Tags: derivatives, calculus

So, we know the [triple product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule)

$$\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \right) \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right) = -1$$

provided that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

**My question is:**
Is there a generalization of this identity for $n$ consecutive partial derivatives in a circular permutation, and is that the superintuitive (-1)n ? If so, can someone provide the link of a proof (or write it down, maybe)?

Plus, why haven't I found anything on this topic online? Isn't it possible to find such expressions in thermodynamics (fundamental relations for instance)? How do we "attack" these expressions?

Comment: How exactly do we know that from thermodynamics?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) is the wiki page for the identity you are after. This is a pure maths question and should probably be moved to math SE.

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1944126/11127