# Cancelling differential terms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, differential-algebra

Can we cancel two differential terms while they are in a ratio. For example if we have (dx/dt) / (dy/dt), can we just directly cancel dt by dt and write it as dx/dy. I mean is is this step allowed?

Comment: Fine, but see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942457/understanding-frac-partial-x-partial-y-frac-partial-y-partial-z-frac

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown for total derivatives (is there a better term?), is this always true?

Comment: The "cancellation of differential terms" in $(dx/dt)/(dy/dt)$ can be considered an abuse of notation of the already abusive notation of Leibnitz.

Answer (score -1):

Yes
The reason for that is quite simple because in differential calculus the Letter "d" denotes a certain amount of change in a quantity
So "dx/dy" means "change in x with respect to change in y". By that logic, "dt" in both terms represent change in quantity "t". Being the same "term" they can be cancelled to create a ratio which gives the proportion of change in one quantity with respect to the another.