# Does $\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}=\frac{dy}{dx}$ always work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let consider the system: $$\begin{cases}\dot x=x\\ \dot y=-y+x^2.\end{cases}$$

To solve this system, my teacher made:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=(-y+x^2)\frac{1}{dx/dt}=(-y+x^2)\frac{1}{x}.$$

And thus $y(x)=\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{c}{x}.$

> Question:  Does this method always work? And if yes why?

Because I have the impression that it really simplify the problem, and I know that: $$\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$ is not always true as [this can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392770/proof-on-showing-if-fx-y-z-0-then-product-of-partial-derivatives-evaluated-at).
So why does it work here ?

Comment: Note that the solution is not complete at this point, as the original independent variable is $t$. But here you can trivially solve the first equation and then insert into the found formula.

Comment: You linked to a question about partial derivatives. Your system uses ordinary derivatives.

Comment: There are involved two equivalent (?) representation kinds. A parametric one $(x(t), y(t))$ and an explicit one after $t$ elimination $y = f(x)$

Comment: @Cesareo Not quite equivalent. The solutions $F(x,y) = c$ are a family of curves which fill the phase plane, called the orbits. We can determine all points which are reached on a solution $(x(t),y(t))$ for all $t$, given $(x(0),y(0))$. This is enough if $t$ is just a parameter and nothing else, but often, $t$ is a physical variable (such as time) and we may want to know the solution at a particular time $t^*$ or what happens as $t\to\infty$, which cannot be deduced from the $F(x,y)=c$ equation alone.

Answer (score 3):

It does always work, and it is called [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Answer (score 1):

If $y(x) = y(x(t))$, then by the chain rule

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} $$

Divide out $\frac{dx}{dt}$ from both sides.